# Create several columns of lagged variables for different groups

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, purrr

I'm trying to add columns of lagged variables to my dataframe. I'm having trouble with this, as I have several groups (countries in my example below) for which I want to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~country, ~variable, 
  #--|--|----
  1997, "USA", 28,
  1998, "USA", 40,
  1999, "USA", 30,
  2000, "USA", 39,
  2001, "USA", 55,
  2002, "USA", 53,
  2003, "USA", 64,
  2004, "USA", 40,
  2005, "USA", 30,
  2006, "USA", 39,
  2007, "USA", 55,
  2008, "USA", 53,
  2009, "USA", 71,
  2010, "USA", 44,
  2011, "USA", 40,
  2012, "USA", 17,
  2013, "USA", 39,
  2014, "USA", 55,
  2015, "USA", 53,
  1997, "France", 13,
  1998, "France", 42,
  1999, "France", 37,
  2000, "France", 11,
  2001, "France", 55,
  2002, "France", 53,
  2003, "France", 31,
  2004, "France", 10,
  2005, "France", 30,
  2006, "France", 37,
  2007, "France", 54,
  2008, "France", 58,
  2009, "France", 50,
  2010, "France", 40,
  2011, "France", 49,
  2012, "France", 14,
  2013, "France", 34,
  2014, "France", 53,
  2015, "France", 50
)
nlags <- 1:10
df_lags <- map(.x = nlags,
               .f = ~ lag(df$variable, .x)) %>% 
  as.data.frame
names(df_lags) <- paste0("lag_", nlags)

df <- df %>% 
  bind_cols(df_lags)
```

This gets it mostly right, **but lags it also takes the lag across groups**! So, afterwards, row 20 looks like this:

```
---------------------------------
| 1997 | France | 13 | 53 | ... | 
---------------------------------
```

But that `53` is taken from the `USA` group, when it should just be an `NA` instead.

I've tried this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  map(.x = nlags,
      .f = ~ lag(variable, .x))
```

But that doesn't work:

```
Error in lag(variable, .x) : object 'variable' not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post an example of the data you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be easier with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0("lag_", nlags) := shift(variable, nlags), country]
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be useful. We can split the data frame by `country`, conduct the same operation for each `country`, and then merge the results. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

nlags <- 1:10

df2 <- df %>%
  split(.$country) %>%
  map_dfr(function(df){
    df_lags <- map(nlags, ~lag(df$variable, .x)) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      setNames(paste0("lag_", nlags))
    df <- bind_cols(df, df_lags)
  })
```

Comment: This gets the lags for the country wrong. So `France`'s lags are attached to `USA` columns and vice versa. Maybe that's because those functions sort the countries alphabetically at some point? An option could be to keep a column for year and country and then do an `left_join(df, df_lags, by = c('year', 'country')`.

Comment: @ulima2_ Thanks for letting me know the issue. You are right. The output from `split` is based on alphabetical order. My solution is to move `bind_col` to the `map_dfr` so each `df_lags` is combined to the right subset of `df`. I have updated  my post. Thanks.